# Use joins for condition over each specific record - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and stuck in between when I'm facing this situation:

I have a `Car model`, `Location Model` and a `Ride Model`

and relationships like as:

```
Car [id, title, is_active, is_online ]
has_many :locations
has_name :rides

CarLocation [id, latitude, longitude, car_id]
belongs_to :car

Ride [id, slat, slng, elat, elng, is_accepted, is_completed, is_cancelled ]
belongs_to car
```

I want to get all **car_locations** whose **car** is *active* now, *online* and that car should not have any current ride, means **car should not have any ride with   (`is_accepted==true and is_completed==false and is_cancelled==false`)**

I have used something like,

```
@carlocations = CarLocation.joins([car: :rides]).where( "cars.is_online=? and cars.is_active=? and (rides.is_accepted !=? and rides.is_completed!= ? and rides.is_cancelled !=?)", category.id, true, true,false,true,true).distinct(:car)
```

but not getting the correct result.

Comment: You need a car_id column in your ride table. As long as that exists @Deepak Mahakale's answer is good

Comment: ofcours it is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass 5 values to the query you're only sending 3

```
("cars.is_online=? and cars.is_active=? and (rides.is_accepted =? and rides.is_completed= ? and rides.is_cancelled =?)", category.id, true, true)
```

Try this query

```
@carlocations = 
  CarLocation
  .joins(car: :rides)
  .where(
    is_online: true, is_active: true, 
    rides: { is_accepted: true, is_completed: false, is_cancelled: false }
  )
```

Also, check this whether you missed the `:` in `belongs_to car` or it's just a typo

```
Ride [id, slat, slng, elat, elng, is_accepted, is_completed, is_cancelled ]
belongs_to :car
```

Comment: sorry that was the typo, now see my problem again please and help me